# USB to VGA video adapter

Tags: video

I'm having a hard time finding reliable info on this subject, but I'm looking for a usb to vga ( or dvi ) adapter for a Ubuntu 10.10 installation on a laptop.

I'm currently using the regular vga external port of my laptop so I have a dual video output but I'd like to a third monitor attached to this setup.

Note: The 2 monitor that I've got are wide resolution so the dualhead2go is not giving me enough workspace making the resolution really poor and uncomfortable.

Thanks for your comments,

Phil

Comment: What do you mean by "wide resolution" (that expression makes no sense in English) and why does that mean the dualhead2go is not good enough?

Answer (score 2):

I can't point you to a device that definitely works but a lot of them use chipsets that are compatible with the (in Ubuntu included) module sisusbvga.

You can read more about it (including example companies and chipsets) [HERE](http://www.winischhofer.net/linuxsisusbvga.shtml).

Basically you need to `sudo modprobe sisusbvga` and then it should work after [editing your xorg.conf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB2VGA) to tell your linux how to treat the new device.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've taken the chance of ordering a dell device... I'm going to test your suggestion and let the community know about...

Comment: @PhilR: how did it go?